$\text{Pic}^0(X)$ consisting of holomorphic structures on the trivial smooth line bundle.
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and consider the Chern class homomorphism
$$
c_1:\text{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X,\Bbb Z).
$$
It is stated that the kernel of this map
$$
\text{Pic}^0(X):=\ker(c_1),
$$
i.e. the Picard variety of $X$ being the group of line bundles with vanishing first Chern class is equivalent with the set (group?) of holomorphic structures on the
trivial smooth line bundle.
I'm having difficulties understanding this equivalence. If $X \times \Bbb C$ is the trivial line bundle, then its clear that $c_1(X \times \Bbb C) = 0$, but if $L \in \operatorname{Pic}^0(X)$, how do you obtain a holomorphic structure on $X \times \Bbb C$? There seems to be a nuance here with smooth and holomorphic vector bundles which I don't quite get.

If $X$ is a projective variety and $c_1(L) = 0$, then $L$ deforms holomorphically to the trivial bundle. Ehresmann’s theorem them identifies the fibers of this deformation with different complex structures of the trivial bundle.

I think I just needed to understand what $\text{Pic}^0(X)$ really is. This thing consists of topologically/smoothly trivial line bundles -- they are isomorphic to the trivial line bundle $X \times \Bbb C$ as smooth complex line bundles. Now if $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle that is topologically trivial, i.e. $c_1(L) = 0$, then I think that using the smooth isomorphism $L \to X\times \Bbb C$ one can pushforward the holomorphic structure $\bar{\partial}_L$ of $L$.
